# Фильтрация таблицы в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

Есть таблица(PostgreSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id int NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  middle_name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO users (id, last_name, first_name, middle_name) 
VALUES
  ('1', 'Иванов','Андрей','Петрович'),
  ('2', 'Петров','Иван','Андреевич'),
  ('3', 'Иванов','Виталий','Иванович'),
  ('4', 'Сергеев','Петр','Витальевич'),
  ('5', 'Андреев','Сергей','Сидорович');
```

На вход подаётся параметр **query**. При этом **query** может быть: Иванов Сергей Петрович, Сергей Иванов,Сергей Петрович Иванов, Сергей и т.д. Написать запрос, возвращающий записи, в ФИО которых входят слова из **query**. Если query='иван иван' возвращаем 3 запись, а первую не возвращаем.

Как можно это осуществить

Comment: Вряд ли у вас получится, ибо тут нужен нечёткий поиск, который при этом понимает логику русского имени.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Postgresql Выборка по строке ФИО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488051/postgresql-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%a4%d0%98%d0%9e)

Answer (score -1):

Я не знаю, как это сделать в Postgresql, но вот пример того, как реализовать это в MS SQL Server. Может быть, это даст некоторую идею.

Алгоритм использует XQuery и его количественные выражения (Quantified Expressions).

Частичное сравнение также очень легко реализовать, но я не хотел усложнять решение.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da0273612b56a09a780f0f95664e58fa)

> T-SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
  id int NOT NULL,
  last_name Nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
  first_name Nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
  middle_name Nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (id, last_name, first_name, middle_name) 
VALUES
  ('1', N'Иванов', N'Андрей', N'Петрович'),
  ('2', N'Петров', N'Иван', N'Андреевич'),
  ('3', N'Иванов', N'Виталий', N'Иванов'),
  ('4', N'Сергеев', N'Петр', N'Витальевич'),
  ('5', N'Андреев', N'Сергей', N'Сидорович');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Separator NCHAR(1) = SPACE(1)
    , @parameterXML NVARCHAR(1024)
    , @parameter NVARCHAR(100) = N'Иванов Иванов';

SET @parameterXML = N'<source><row>' 
    + REPLACE(@parameter, @Separator, N'</row><row>') 
    + N'</row></source>';

SELECT ID, last_Name, first_name, middle_name
   , CAST('<root>' + @parameterXML 
        + '<target><row>' 
        + last_name + '</row><row>' 
        + first_name + '</row><row>' 
        + middle_name + '</row>' 
        + '</target></root>' AS XML)
    .value('every $r in /root/source/row/text()
            satisfies ($r = (/root/target/row/text())
            and count(/root/source/row[./text()[1] eq $r]) = count(/root/target/row[./text()[1] eq $r])
         )', 'VARCHAR(5)') AS result
FROM @tbl;
```

> результат

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
| ID | last_Name | first_name | middle_name | result |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | Иванов    | Андрей     | Петрович    | false  |
|  2 | Петров    | Иван       | Андреевич   | false  |
|  3 | Иванов    | Виталий    | Иванов      | true   |
|  4 | Сергеев   | Петр       | Витальевич  | false  |
|  5 | Андреев   | Сергей     | Сидорович   | false  |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+--------+
```